# how do i display a custom message after submitting a form?

Tags: php, forms, validation, email, phpmailer

I have a html form that sends email, using phpMailer, after its submission. Everything works fine but i want to display a message **on the form** when the email is sent.
With my code, a message is displayed on an empty white page.

My php code:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'] ?? '';
$email = $_POST['email'] ?? '';
$msg = $_POST['msg'] ?? '';

  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
  use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

  require 'vendor/autoload.php';

  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

  try {

    $mail->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Port=587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure='tls';
    $mail->Username='email@email.com';
    $mail->Password='password';

    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);  // who send the email
    $mail->addAddress('email@email.com'); // who recive the email

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Portfolio response';
    $mail->Body = $msg;

    $mail->send();
     echo 'Your message has been sent!';
    } catch (Exception $e){
        echo '';
    }

?>
```

*Your message has been sent!* is obviously the message displayed.

Html form code:

```
 <form action="mail-handler.php" method="POST" id="contact-form">
              <span class="contacts-text" id="first-contacts-text">To get in touch with me, please compile this form.</span>
              <span class="contacts-text">I will reply as soon as possible. Thank you!</span>
              <ul class="form-content">
                  <li class="form-input">
                      <label for="name" class="label">Full name</label>
                      <input class="input" id="name" type="text" name="name" required>
                  </li>
                  <li class="form-input">
                      <label for="email" class="label">E-mail</label>
                      <input class="input" id="mail" type="text" name="email" required>
                  </li>
                  <li class="form-input">
                      <label for="msg" class="label">Insert text</label>
                      <textarea class="input" id="comment" type="text" name="msg" cols="30" rows="10" style="resize: none;" required></textarea>
                  </li>
                  <li class="form-input" id="last-input">
                      <input class="input" id="form-button" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" onclick="sendEmail()">
                  </li>
              </ul>
            </form>
```

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Are these PHP and HTML blocks placed in one file or multiple?

Comment: Hi @biesior, two different files

Comment: then update your question and show us how do you redirect to the  second file fith form after mail submit

Comment: i mean, the data sent by the html form (made in my index.html file) are storage into the mail-handler.php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change the name of your `index.html` to `index.php`, so it can be parsed by a PHP interpreter.

Next modiy your success statement body, i.e.:

```php
try {
    $mail->send();
    header('Location: index.php?mailsent=1');
    die(); // we don't want exactly anything after sending redirect header.
} catch (Exception $e){
    echo '';
}
```

Finally in file with your form add the message if `$_GET['mailsent']` variable is available.

```php
HTML code of your page...
...
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['mailsent']) && intval($_GET['mailsent']) == 1 ){
        echo '<div class="messagesbox">Mail was sent</div>';
    }
?>
<form action="mail-handler.php" method="POST" id="contact-form">
   ... your form body skipped here
</form>
```

#### Other options

If you don't want to pass arguments via GET array, you can try to use sessions.

Also, you can just create a static `thankyou.html` page and redirect the user there, after mail submitting

Also, if you move the whole PHP code for the form submittion into `index.php` you won't need to make redirects.

Finally, as you added - while it's *one-page* site you should also consider using AJAX probably with jQuery - that way you're will be able to submit the form without leaving the page, display messages without reloading, etc. Anyway, this topic is definitely too broad to be described in this answer and I can only suggest you get familiar with [jQuery AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: ok this is fantastic! only two simple questions: is there a way to prevent the load of the page? also, is this text customizable? thanks a lot, you already made my day

Comment: What do you mean with "*prevent the page load*"? That's the simple code of HTML you can paste anything you want, from simple text to advanced HTML structure with modal...

Comment: sorry, i didn't tell you that this is a one page portfolio so, after sending the email, the page loads and the user is redirected at the beginning of the page, making the "mail was sent" message useful. Probably in this case is better to use the "thankyou.html" page.

Comment: @DarioMarin check additional options in my edit, two last paragraphs